# Finding a basis for $W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_3 \mid p(-1)=p(2)=0\}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Find a basis for $W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_3 \mid p(-1)=p(2)=0\}.$

First off, $\mathbb{P}_n$ denotes the vector space with polynomials with degree $n$ or lower.

My work/thinking:

I know that for $\mathbb{P}_n$, its standard basis would be $\{1,x,x^2, \cdots,x^n\}.$

Would this be a correct basis for $W$?

$W_{\text{Basis}}=\{1,(x+1)(x-2),(x+1)^2(x-2),(x+1)^3(x-2)\}$

Since the problem wants the basis for polynomials in $\mathbb{P}_3$, with the roots being $x=1$ and $x=2$, I just thought of one way for the polynomial to have the given roots, and then I just raised its degree from $1$ to $3$. I did that because from what I understand about polynomials in sets, they are linearly independent if each of the elements in the set have different degrees. (Please correct me if I am wrong about this.)

Comment: The element $1$ surley isn't in the basis, note $1(x)=1\neq 0$ for every $x$

Comment: $(x+1)^3(x-2)$ has degree four and shouldn't be in the basis. You missed $(x-2)^2(x+1)$.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan what do you mean by "the answer will still be $0$"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Nevermind, I don't know what was running through my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:**
You have too many elements in your bases.  First of all, $p(x)=1$ satisfies neither of $W$'s defining properties, and $(x+1)^3(x-2)$ has degree greater than $3$.

However, $\{(x+1)(x-2),(x+1)^2(x-2)\}$ are indeed linearly independent and both within the set.  Now, is this a complete basis?  Why or why not?

**Hint 2**
We can write polynomials $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$ as vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d\end{bmatrix}^T$.  In that case, this subspace is the following solution-space for $\vec x$: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 2 & 4 & 8
\end{bmatrix} \vec x=\vec 0
$$

Comment: That basis looks good to me. Okay, just to make sure I understand: when it says $p(x) \in \mathbb{P}_3$, the polynomial's degree after multiplication by the other polynomial should be degree 3 or less. Secondly, $1$ is not in the basis because it does not fit the $p(-1)=p(2)=0$ condition on W. So this means that the basis won't have a polynomial with degree $o$. Also, the basis will not have a polynomial with degree $1$, because both polynomials are of degree 1, and their product will yield a polynomial of degree 2. Is what I said correct?

Comment: Also, just to make sure I understand one last thing: Your basis is correct, but this basis would also be correct right? $\{(x+1)(x-2),(x+1)(x-2)^2\}?$

Comment: Your basis won't contain any polynomial of degree $0$ or $1$ because there is no polynomial of degree $0$ or $1$ in $W$. Your other choice of basis also works.  In fact, you could also use $\{(x+1)^2(x-2),(x+1)(x-2)^2\}$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you understand that second hint as well? In general, I find these problems much easier to understand if you can think in terms of linear transformations. Putting the matrix into rref, you get $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&2\\ 0&1&1&3\end{bmatrix}$$ which is to say that you could have also used the basis $\{-2-3x+x^3,-2-x+x^2\}$

Comment: Yes, I've been trying that method out on some textbook problems. It does make it easier.

Comment: Good! Looks like you know your stuff then

Answer (score 2):

Let $P \in  W$

$P(-1)=0$ so $X+1\mid P$

$P(2)=0$ so $X-2\mid P$

Since $X+1 \land X-2 = 1$, $(X+1)(X-2)\mid P$

So we can find $Q$ so that $P=(X+1)(X-2)Q$

Since $P$ is of degree at most $3$, $Q$ is of degree at most $1$ so there is an $\alpha,\beta  \in \Bbb R$ so that $Q=\alpha X + \beta$

Let $S=\{(X+1)(X-2)(\alpha X + \beta) \mid \alpha,\beta \in \Bbb R\}$

We have just shown that $S\subseteq W$

Now let $P\in S$. From its expression, it's obvious that $P(-1)=0=P(2)$ so $S\subseteq W$

So we have that $S=W$

Can you find a basis for $S$?

---

By that way, in case you have already studied linear systems, it is easy to see $W$ is of dimension $2$.

You want the elements of $\Bbb P_3$, polynomials $aX^3+bx^2+cX+d$, that satisfy two equations: $-a+b-c+d=0$ and $8a+4b+2c+d=0$. Since both equations are linearly independent, you get a subspace of dimension $\dim \Bbb P_3 - $"number of linearly independant equations "$=4-2=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Just as another way of solving this problem. You can use the method of undetermined coefficients: you apply your conditions for a general polynom $a_{n} x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$ of degree less or equal then $n$. Applying restrictions gives you a system of linear equations. Choosing the basis for a solution of this system is equivalent to choosing basis in space of polynoms with such properties.